# Typo in book or I am wrong?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, tangent-line, slope

Find the equation of the tangent to the parabola $y = x^2$,
if the $x$-intercept of the tangent is $2$.

Now
$$y = mx + b$$
$$0 = m(2) + 2$$
$$m = -1$$

so
$$m = \frac{y-0}{x-2}$$
$$m(x-2) = y$$
$$-x-y = -2$$

but the book answer is

$$8x-y =16$$

Comment: How do you know that $b=2$?

Comment: @Randall the x-intercept of the tangent is 2. given in the question

Comment: That means $(2,0)$ is on the graph of $y=mx+b$.  It doesn't mean that $b=2$.

Comment: Also, just by the graph of $y=x^2$, if the $x$-int of a tangent line is going to be $2$, the line must have positive slope.

Comment: Start by drawing a picture of the parabola and eyeballing where that tangent will be on the picture. Then you will have a common sense check on any algebra you do. That's good strategy for many such problems.

Comment: @Randall that's correct

Comment: How can I find the slope then?

Comment: Perhaps you start from the other end. The  line tangent at $(a,a^2)$ is given by $y-a^2=2a(x-a).$ When $y=0$ then you determine $x$ in terms of $a.$ Next you find the value of $a$ for which $x=2.$

Comment: Note that $b$ is the $y$-intercept, not the $x$-intercept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say $(X,Y)$ is the point where the line is tangent to the parabola.  Then $Y=X^2$.
Furthermore, using calculus (one of the question tags), the tangent line has slope $2X$, and we are given that the $x$-intercept is $2$.

So the equation for the tangent line is $y=2Xx+b$, which becomes $X^2=2X^2+b$ at the tangent point and $0=2X\cdot2+b$ at the $x$-intercept, so $0=X^2+b$ and $0=4X+b$.  From there we see that $X=4$ (or $0$, but then the tangent line would not have a unique $x$-intercept) and $b=-16$, and so the equation for the tangent line is $y=8x-16$.

Answer (score 2):

$y = mx + b$

$(2,0)$ lies on the line.

$0 = 2m + b\\
b = -2m$

Here is the error in the original post.

$y = mx - 2m$ is tangent to $y = x^2$

$x^2 = mx - 2m\\
x^2 - mx + 2m = 0$

We must find the value of $m$ such that there is exactly one solution to this quadratic.

We can use the quadratic formula:

$x = \frac {-m \pm \sqrt {m^2 - 8m}}{2}$

In order to have 1 solution $m^2 - 8m = 0$

$m = 0$ or $m = 8$

Case 1: $m=0$
$y= 0$ is tangent to the curve and does go through the point $(2,0)$ but as it represents the entire x-axis, it would not be accurate to say that this line has an x-intercept.

Case 2: $m = 8$
$y = 8x - 16$ which is equivalent to the book's solution.

Answer (score 2):

In general for $y=f(x)$ the line tangent at $(a,f(a))$ is given by
$y-f(a)=f'(a)(x-a).$
For $f(x)=x^2$ we get $y-a^2=2a(x-a).$ The slope must be nonzero, i.e. $a\neq 0.$ When $y=0$ then $x={a\over 2}.$ Hence $a=4$ and the equation of the tangent line is $y-16=8(x-4),$ i.e. $y=8x-16.$

Answer (score 1):

Book answer is right.

We want $m$, $b$, $x_0$ such that $y=mx+b$ touches the parabola $y=x^2$ at point $x_0$.

We know $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}x^2=2x$, so since the slope will be tangent to the parabola at the kissing point we know $m=2x_0$. From $0=2m+b$ we can conclude $b=-4x_0$.
Now we find $x_0$:
\begin{align}
\frac{y_0-y_\text{intercept}}{x_0-x_\text{intercept}}&=m\\
\frac{y_0-0}{x_0-2}&=2x_0\\
y_0&=2x_0^2-4x_0\\
x_0^2&=2x_0^2-4x_0\\
0&=x_0^2-4x_0\\
x_0&=\frac{-(-4)\pm\sqrt{(-4)^2-4(1)(0)}}{2(1)}\\
&=\frac{4\pm\sqrt{16+0}}{2}\\
&=4,0
\end{align}
We can discard $x_0=0$ as a viable solution.
Now we have:
\begin{align}
m&=2x_0=8\\
b&=-4x_0=-16\\
y&=mx+b\\
y&=8x-16\\
8x-y&=16
\end{align}